# How do you make the browser not cache React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, browser-cache

I've tried "no-cache" in the metatag, but it doesn't seem to work and users of my page are getting issues due to cache. I need to not cache the browser due to NPM package updates and the errors keep occuring until cache is deleted. This can be due to components that get updated and contain a bug from a library I'm using.

Comment: Usually by having a hash in the name of each file, so if it changes it's no longer a cache hit. Research "cache busting".

Comment: @jonrsharpe By each file do you mean in entire project? We already have a hash in the meta-tag that is same as git-commit

Comment: In the _outputs_ from the build. E.g. here are some outputs from a CRA app: https://github.com/textbook/abv/tree/gh-pages/static/js.

Comment: So we can do this for each build? @jonrsharpe

Comment: That's going to depend on how you're making that build, read the documentation for the relevant tools. CRA does it automatically, but if you're using e.g. Webpack directly you'll have to configure it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe We are using webpack.. so I guess I'll need to investigate it. Thanks man.

Answer (score -1):

If you are having caching issues on the images then what you can do is add a random number on the image. So every time your app renders it render a new image

`<img src={randomImg+"?v="+new Math.random()} />`

It will give a completly new image every time something renders

To chache image on each render is not good in performance. So to get rid of render image on each render instead of using Math.random() you can also use Date and can refresh the image every minute or hour whatever time you prefer.

Comment: The best would be to delete cache for each build